# Give an example of a set which is a neighborhood of each of its points.

Tags: real-analysis

> Give an example of a set which is a neighborhood of each of its points.

The open interval (2,3).

> Give an example: a set which is not a neighborhood of any of its points.

Why is the finite set {1,2,3} an example of this? How does it not satisfy the definition of neighborhood? [image]

Comment: Do you know the definition of neighbourhood? Can you try to apply the definition to the problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a point in $(2, 3)$. Then $(2, 3)$ is an open subset of the real line that contains the point, hence, a neighborhood.

On the other hand, the set $\{1, 2, 3\}$ is does not not contain any open set on the real line, hence could not be a neighborhood.

Recall that a neighbodhood is a set containing an open set containing the point.

Comment: Isn't a neighbordhood of a point $p$ a set that contains some open subset containing $p$?

Comment: Indeed, I will edit my answer to make it clearer.